# How to get user input in scene based application using samsung smart tv

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Am new to develop app in samsung smart tv in normal application i use IME and got output and my problem is by  using scene based application how i will get user input and make process it ?  and Second one i am using samsung smart tv sdk4.5 in that i try add js file in scene.js file but $.sf.loadJS is not working it shows.."Error Detail: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadJS' of undefined" , like this plzee tell me solution for this without this solution i cannot look forward.thanks in advance

Comment: 1. You may post your code (or at least some of it) because it's very difficult to tell out of the blue 2. In order to use IME, you need to have <input>-tags. You can use <div> tags and convert them to sfTextInput (in your JS) but I don't think you can process any information with sfTextInput.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code looks like, but usually the code for native object from SDK is non-compatible between scene-based and normal project (actually the library loaded from those 2 template kind like different)

Scene-based library usually all wrapped in "sf" object. Please look at the links below

http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00009/uiapi_textinput_textinput.html
http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00009/uiapi_textinput_sftextinput.html